# How can I pair up wiimote plus to my Ubuntu 12.04 machine?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, gamepad, wii

It keeps asking for the PIN, and the option of connecting a device without PIN is not added to Ubuntu for some reason.

I know there are things like wiican, but the package is not available for some reason.
Plus I just want it to pair up with my system, and let Dolphin-Emu do the rest, I dont want to emulate a mouse or anything.

Comment: A default "pin" for bluetooth is 0000, did you try that?

Comment: Yes, it says the process failed

Comment: See my answer below, I believe i found the package you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [GetDeb installer for wiican here](http://www.getdeb.net/software/wiican) if you want, according to the [WiiCan project on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/wiican), GetDeb manages the debian packages for that project.

I noticed you mentioned 'wiican' in your question, so I thought I'd help out here.

#### To use the GetDeb Package and Repository on 12.04:

(http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/12.04/#how_to_install)
Use the following instructions:

1: Install the [getdeb package](http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb).

Or configure the repository manually:

> Go to System-Administration-Software Sources, Third-Party Software tab, Add:
>       deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps
>
> Add the repository GPG key, open a terminal window and type:
>       wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

2: **Run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal.**

3: Click the "Install this now" button below the screenshot of the desired application.

4: **If you are using Kubuntu please check [bug 476853](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/476853).**

5: If the application cannot be found, run this command and try again: `sudo apt-get update`

Then try installing the package you are looking to install (wiican).

---

If that doesn't work, you may need to google around to find the correct pairing pin for the wiimote.  (note that for almost every bluetooth device, a secure pairing pin is used.  it prevents malicious access to devices)

Comment: Nope, the Software Center Says page not found.

Comment: Actually, I got somewhere. I noticed that the bluetooth-man applet is capable of adding the device and successfully pairing it. However, the controller turns off like it hasnt been paired.

Comment: I think you need to add the GetDeb repos first, i forgot to give you a link to that.  You could always build from source, too, for wiican.

Comment: @Thompson I've updated the answer accordingly, to have the "How to install the GetDeb Repos" included.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The thing is, it appears I got myself a new model of the Wii Remote, where Nintendo switched something making it harder to make to work. Dolphin-Emu team hasn't come around to fixing it up for windows yet, so that would explain why linux drivers didnt work for me (the repos are quiet old).

Comment: which Ubuntu, @Thompson?